# Redirect (?) issue in CakePHP 1.3: "Failed to load source"

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-1.3

From the `/posts/edit`-view I'm submitting a form to the action `addCategory` in my `Post` controller.
The action does all the work it has to do, and subsequently calls `$this->redirect($this->referer());`.

At first sight my app works fine, but I encountered some hickups when moving to a production server. Monitoring the calls in Firebug I see that the action acually returns a `302 Found` but the 'Response' is `Failed to load source for: http://localhost/xps/posts/addCategory`.
This happens on both dev en production servers, only on the production server it makes the redirect flow fail. On both servers the controller actions are executed well: category is added.

Removing all the code in the action results in the same failure. Removing the redirect removes the failure, but that's not getting me anywhere.

A second (though maybe irrelevant) irregularity is that the submit method of the form is identified as `PUT` in Firebug although I explicitly set it to `POST` in Cake.

I recently switched from CakePHP 1.3.4 to 1.3.6, but reversing does not change the behavior
I use the RequestHandler, Session and Auth components and call parent::beforeFilter() in beforeFilter().

I also found the following thread http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/puzzle-over-activity-td1260972.html It suggests to remove `$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';` but I don't have that stated anywhere anyway.

Does anyone have an idea where to look next?

Comment: Naíve question, but were the caches all cleared? Was it possible to restart the underlying web server?

Comment: Caches are indeed cleared and I restarted the webserver which didn't change the result.
If I change the redirect statement to a render statement, the error disappears (but the page is ofcourse a bit odd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it.
The `Failed to load source` is still there but is not the cause of failure.
In one of my Behaviors I had a space after `?>` which messed up the headers, which made me look into the wrong detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but if you are using Security component, it might cause problems. Also, sometimes when using the ajax and sessions it can cause problems. Maybe if the page requires sessions, you could try it without sessions and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the same thing and had already enabled the Security component. I can't enable Sessions because the user has to be logged in: too much side implications.